# Trying to output letter grades

Tags: c#

I am in trying to create a form that converts decimals to a letter grade. The issue is that the letterGrade does not exist in that current context of the method but how do I essentially get it to "return". I am new to C#. I will appreciate any help I can get.

```
    private void txtNumberGrade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumberGrade.Focus();
    }

    private void txtLetterGrade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

//error at this line below

```
    txtLetterGrade.Text = letterGrade;
```

//error at this line above

```
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal score = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNumberGrade.Text);
        string letterGrade = "";
        if (score >= 90)
        {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }
        else if (score >= 80)
        {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }
        else if (score >= 70)
        {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }
        else if (score >= 60)
        {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }
        else if (score >= 0)
        {
            letterGrade = "F";
        }
        else {
            letterGrade = "Z";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't change the txtLetterGrade again inside a "TextChanged" event handler. It will run into an infinite loop.

Comment: `if  (decimal.TryParse(txtNumberGrade.Text, out decimal score))` etc... You can create a static function to return what you need when you click the button. The snippet I put is to help ensure that the `Text` property can be parsed successfully...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I should alter the if else?

Comment: What is the goal here? When the text changes you want to get the grade to another textbox? If this is the case, create a function that takes the string representation and try and convert it to a decimal, if you can, return what grade it is, otherwise something else...

Comment: Yes the goal is the user type in their decimal grade in one text box and the other textbox it will populate their generated letter grade

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I feel like making another function is too complicated. You couldn't just return string letterGrade.

Comment: Be aware that Visual Studio is the tool you use to author your code. It does not execute it. Your question does not pertain to the Visual Studio application.

Comment: @JohnnyDepp your button click event is a method, not a routine, it will not *return* anything.

Comment: @JohnnyDepp I should have worded the above, `the click event is a method, not a function as it doesn't return anything`.

Answer (score 1):

What you *could* do is create a function to return the grade you need. Below I am using the [Decimal.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) which converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal equivalent and a return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed. If it did succeed, then `score` would have this value.

```
 private static string GetGrade(string decGrade)
 {
    if (decimal.TryParse(decGrade, out decimal score))
    {
        if (score >= 90)
        {
           return "A";
        }
        else if (score >= 80)
        {
           return "B";
        }
        else if (score >= 70)
        {
           return "C";
        }
        else if (score >= 60)
        {
           return "D";
        }
        else if (score >= 0)
        {
           return "F";
        }
        else 
        {
           return "Z";
        }
    }
    else { return "NA"; }
 }
```

Now you can call this in the `TextChanged` event as such:

```
private void txtNumberGrade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtLetterGrade.Text = GetGrade(txtNumberGrade.Text);      
}
```

References:

**Decimal.TryParse Method** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you for your time spent on this I appreciate it

Comment: @JohnnyDepp it's really no problem, I've helped someone, that's what matters. I hope you found it to be helpful and fix your issues.